# regex - how to match >first tag in email address?

Tags: regex

I need to remove last tag from email address like that:

```
foo+bar@baz.com       =>   foo@baz.com
foo+bar+baz@xyz.com   =>   foo+bar@xyz.com
foo@bar.com           =>   foo@bar.com     // no change
```

This regex does work but it removes both tags even though it's ungreedy `+?`:

```
\+{1}(.+?)@{1}
```

[PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/513435987b45ea8180e20a01cf41fa13b518f573)

I tried negative lookahead but it doesn't work as expected, still removes both tags:

```
\+{1}.+(?!\+).+@{1}
```

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AEqUAE/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\+[^+@]+@
```

and replace with `@`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/56ku0F/1)

**Details**

- `\+` - a plus
- `[^+@]+` - 1 or more chars other than `+` and `@`
- `@` - a `@` (to "anchor" the search, thus, we need to replace with this char)

If there is a requirement to only remove that part after `+` before the *last* `@`, use

```
(.*)\+[^+@]+(@[^@]*$)
```

and replace with `$1$2`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/56ku0F/4).

Here,

- `(.*)` - Group 1: captures any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\+[^+@]+` - see pattern above
- `(@[^@]*$)` - Group 2: a `@`, and then 0+ chars other than `@` till the end of the string.